# Outlook AppointmentItem - How do I programmatically add RTF to its Body?

Tags: outlook

I would like to set the `Body` of an `AppointmentItem` to a string of RTF that contains an embedded image.  Setting `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem.Body` results in the RTF appearing as-is in the appointment.

I have tried using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) which wraps the appointment and exposes an `RTFBody` property, but the RTF formatting (including the image) is lost.

In this example (which doesn't have an embedded image) the RTF appears in the document as-is.  Has anyone managed to do this?

```
var appointment = (AppointmentItem)app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
appointment.Subject = "test subject";
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
appointment.Body = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test}";
appointment.Save();
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to access the AppointmentItem's GetInspector property, and use it to fetch the underlying WordEditor used to parse the RTF format, something like:

```
var doc = appointment.GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```

and then format the document using doc.Content according to [Word Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best info I have seen on this is as per this answer:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b41acf6f-71c1-4a8b-9662-fbff26ba3a24/

Basically, it's a klunkly 2-step process:

1. Get reference to the WordEditor object
2. Using the clipboard, copy and paste the formatted content into the editor

Seriously Microsoft, surely you could have come up with a better design.