# Outlook 2007 - How to insert RTF text into an AppointmentItem

Tags: com, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I'm working in outlook 2007 and I need to insert RTF text into the `AppointmentItem`. I've found a few posts that claim you are able to do it with such and such but no actual code showing how to do it. The best source that I have found so far is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555156/outlook-appointmentitem-how-do-i-programmatically-add-rtf-to-its-body)

And I followed it but in the end nothing is getting inserted into the Appointment Item.

The following is what I have:

```cs
Word.Document wd = AppointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;

// *Assume that I have all the RTF text that I want to copy set up and ready in the clipboard and is ready to be inserted(copied) into the Appointment Item.

//This doesnt seem to work
wd.Content.Select();
wd.Content.Paste();

//This also doesnt seem to work
(AppointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document).Content.Select();
(AppointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document).Content.Paste();
```

So according to what I've read and seen this is how your suppose to insert RTF into an appointment item, but I'm still unable to get anything into the `AppointmentItem`.

Now with that being said if i look at this variable:

```cs
(AppointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document).Content.Text;
```

But if I look at `AppointmentItem.Text` it is still unchanged.

Now there is not function that is `AppointmentItem.paste()` or `AppointmentItem.text.paste()` and you don't have access to the RTF variable in the appointment item.

So can anyone tell me what I'm missing? how can I paste to the `AppointmentItem` or actually get RTF text into the `AppointmentItem`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not specifying a selection for a copy and paste.  The copy-and-paste works entirely like a user doing a copy and paste, you have select a range you want first.

Try

```
wd.Sections[1].Range.Copy();
document.Range(0, 0).PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
```

A good write-up you can find similar to this is Tom_Xu MSFT write up in the thread called, "[Load a .doc file content in Outlook.MailItem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/02056c49-f3ac-4e46-bedf-2c6f849d7bce)"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to figure this out with Office 2010, 2013:

```
string sRtfBody = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Century Gothic;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 This course will help you appreciate the beauty of numbers in some ways that you may have never considered.\par}";
Outlook.AppointmentItem aiMeeting = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)this._Outlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
aiMeeting.RTFBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sRtfBody);
```